# Firebase-functions deploy error "Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/root/.config/configstore/firebase-tools.json'"

Tags: linux, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I was trying to implement some new features to my firebase project but when trying to deploy it I got this exception...
I am new to Linux world and I couldn't fix this error :(

I tried with root permissions but I couldn't get anything to work...

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: By any chance, have you installed `firebase-tools` using `sudo`? have you installed it like this? `sudo npm i firebase-tools -g`

Comment: Yes, I did it globally. Luckily I already solved it and everything is working correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by disabling the proxy in the user settings!

[image: Solution]